# jQuery - Reset file input on change

Tags: jquery, file, input

I'm trying to clear the  component if the user attaches a file that is not accepted. I'm trying to do it right after it is attached. I took a look on some examples here, where some of them showed me how to do it with a reset button, that resets the whole form (something that I don't wanna do), or cloning the component (something that I tried but it is not working). I would be glad if someone could help me. Thanks in advance.

Here is an example of what I have:

```
$("#mycomponent").on("change", function()
{
    var extension = $(this).val().split(".").pop().toString();

    if((extension === "pdf") || (extension === "docx") || (extension === "doc"))
    {
        alert("OK");    
    }
    else
    {
        alert("File extension not accepted");

        var mycomponent = $("#mycomponent");
        mycomponent.replaceWith(mycomponent = mycomponent.clone(true));
    }
});
```

Comment: Why not just do a `mycomponent.val("");` ?

Answer (score 4):

You can clear the component with val(), like this:

```
$("#mycomponent").on("change", function()
{
    var extension = $(this).val().split(".").pop().toString();

    if((extension === "pdf") || (extension === "docx") || (extension === "doc"))
    {
        alert("OK");    
    }
    else
    {
        alert("File extension not accepted");

        var mycomponent = $("#mycomponent");
        mycomponent.val("");
    }
});
```

Comment: Funcionou desse jeito também. Valeu!

Answer (score 2):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/376/).**

Using the `wrap()/unwrap()` functions like the following way should work :

```
$(this).wrap('<form>').closest('form').get(0).reset();
$(this).unwrap();
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$("#mycomponent").on("change", function(){
  var extension = $(this).val().split(".").pop().toString();

  if((extension === "pdf") || (extension === "docx") || (extension === "doc"))
  {
    console.log("OK");    
  }
  else
  {
    console.log("File extension not accepted");
    
    $(this).wrap('<form>').closest('form').get(0).reset();
    $(this).unwrap();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="mycomponent" />
```

Comment: Didn't work, the component is still showing the file name attached with the wrong extension

Comment: True, I've updated my answer with working snippet, check please.

Comment: You're no longer using clone, can you edit out that part please (for the sake of people seeing this in future)